# Ren'Py: Syntax errors all over the place

Tags: python, renpy

I first downloaded Ren'py, but already had problems on the start. When opening any of the scripts, that belonged to demo projects, I have been seeing syntax errors on almost every keyword. I tried to search for something like "*define is not defined ren py*", but found nothing - seems there are no special forums for Ren'py, except its own Github. Python was updated yesterday - installation folder is default, same for Ren'py - I tried both 7.5.2 and 8.0.2. Ren'py cannot be installed wrong, because the app is being downloaded ready to launch.
What can be wrong about my installation process?[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpy` is Ren'py's own specialized Python dialect. You're seeing syntax errors because your VSCode has been told to try and parse `rpy` as Python. You'd need to use a package for Ren'py syntax (e.g. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LuqueDaniel.languague-renpy – disclaimer: haven't tried that out).

Furthermore, you don't run `rpy` files using the vanilla Python interpreter (as you're attempting to); you'd run them via [the Ren'py launcher](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/quickstart.html#the-ren-py-launcher) as described in the "Getting Started" tutorial.